# How to use operator+ and operator= together?

Tags: c++, operators, redefinition

I have a little problem with 2 operators in my class.

My class is declared :

```
template <class keyType, class valueType>
class MyMap{

    keyType keys[MAX];
    valueType values[MAX];
    int size;
}
```

I need to redefine the operator [], for example when i call : `std::cout<<MyMap1["a"];`.

```
keyType& operator[] (keyType key){}
```

It works fine. I used it to make assignments too and it was good, for example : `MyMap1["a"]="a1";`

The code was perfect. But in my `operator[]` I increment the `size` parameter and it's usefull only when I want to make an assignment. I dont want to increment it when I only do a `std::cout`.

So maybe i should redefine the `operator=` function but when I can't write :

```
void operator=(valueType value){}
```

Because the left member of `MyMap1["a"]   =   "a1"` is a `keyType` and not a `MyMap` type.

How can i do ?

Comment: If your class is meant to be a K->V map, then the operator[] should be defined as `valueType& operator[] (keyType key)`, because when you write `map[key]` you usually want to read/write to the value-thing stored under that given key..

Comment: Thats correct ! But the two types were String so i didn't see that bug. Any ideas for my problem ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't outputting, per se; it is what you do when the
key isn't present.  I think it's very important that you specify
before going any farther.  There are many possibilities:

- You can do what `std::map` does, and insert it with a default
  value.  This is very convenient in many cases, but it does mean
  that you cannot use `[]` on a const map.
- You can have the operator return a pointer, with a null
  pointer if the object isn't present.  Personally, I don't like
  this for `operator[]`; it means that you have to write things
  like: `ValueType* p = myMap[ key ]; if ( p != NULL ) ...`, which
  doesn't seem natural for `[]`.  (On the other hand, it does work
  well with a `find` or `get` function.)
- You can throw an exception (or even use an assert, if you
  provide a `contains` function, and have it as a precondition of
  `[]`).
- You can return a predefined default value.  This is sort of
  the opposite of the first solution; it means that `operator[]`
  will never change the map, and that there is no need for
  a non-const version.
- Finally (and this seems to be what you are aiming for): you
  can have `operator[]` return a proxy, in order to distiguish
  between `myMap["a"]` used as an rvalue, and `myMap["a"]
  = something`.  My feeling is that this solution doesn't marry
  well with the way C++ works, but it is used in other languages
  (e.g. like Python).

For the last solution, you would use something like:

```
class MyMap
{
    class Proxy
    {
        MyMap* myOwner;
        KeyType myKey;
    public:
        Proxy( MyMap* owner, KeyType key )
            : myOwner( owner )
            , myKey( key )
        {
        }

        Proxy const& operator=( ValueType value ) const
        {
            myOwner->insertOrUpdate( myKey, value );
            return *this;
        }

        operator ValueType() const
        {
            if ( !myOwner->contains( myKey ) ) {
                throw UnknownKeyException( myKey );
            }
            return myOwner->get( myKey );
        }
    };

public:
    Proxy operator[]( KeyType key )
    {
        return Proxy( this, key );
    }
};
```

Comment: Python is more magic than that -- the Python runtime turns `myMap["a"] = "b"` into `myMap.__setitem__("a", "b")`, if `__setitem__` exists. So you don't *normally* need proxy objects AFAIK. I can believe there are uses for them in Python just as there are in C++, but ordinary assignment to a container element isn't one of them :-)

Comment: Also, I wonder whether in C++ there's an argument for combining (1) and (3). That is, have `const V &operator[](const K&)const` throw an exception if the key is missing, while non-const `operator[]` returns a non-const reference and inserts an entry if the key is missing. Handling the same error two different ways is normally a bad idea, but in this case it might match the common usage, and would allow using `operator[]` on const `Mymap` for those who want to catch at a higher level.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes.  I was talking about the standard Python `map`; in addition to being able to redefine `__setitem__` (by deriving from `map`), there's also `__missing__`, which will be called when reading, if the object isn't found.  The important point, here, is that Python does distinguish between reading and writing, which is what we need to proxy for in C++.

Comment: @SteveJessop With regards to combining (1) and (3), I'm a bit sceptical.  It seems too much like trying to use one operator for two different requirements.  And I don't like the idea that the behavior will change if someone adds a `const` that had been initially forgotten.

Comment: I completely agree: an overload that differs solely by the 'const' qualifier should behave consistently with non-const one. 'Const' is meant as a compile-time error check. Mixing behaviors in const/nonconst as (1)+(3) combo would do, is even worse idea than you say. In general, one adds 'const' here and there as a compile-time error check. Anticipating that if it is placed where not applicable, then the compilation would immediatelly break. Making an added 'const' to throw exceptions in runtime is.. as evil as passing zeroed thing& around.

Answer (score 1):

"But in my operator[] I increment the size parameter".

Don't. Check if the key exists, and increment `size` only if a new key is inserted. When you're doing a `std::cout`, presumably you're doing so only on existing key/value pairs.

[edit]
Given the comment, here's an alternative solution. In `operator[]`, return a `MyMap<KeyType, ValueType>::proxy`. This wraps a `MyMap&` and `Key`. Overload `MyMap::proxy::operator=(ValueType)` to assign a new value, and increment `size`. Overload `MyMap::proxy::operator ValueType() const` to get a value. Return `ValueType()` if the key is not present.

Comment: I copy/paste you the same response i told to Paul, but I want to std::cout a key wich is not in my class and I want as output a std::endl

Comment: I've provided inclded a link, you'd be able to borrow much of the code from there

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
auto blah = map[key];
```

the operator[] is called with a `key`, and it returns a value.

When you write:

```
map[key] = blah;
```

then the operator[key] is called with a `key`, and it returns a value, and then operator= is called on the value with `blah` argument.

This means that it might be hard to detect wherever you actually are reading or writing to the map.

However, usually, in the READ case, the case might fall back to an `value const& operator[] const` called, while during the write, it'd be `value& operator[]` **without const** markers. Therefore, you **might** try to overload the operator by const specifier: provide 2 operator[]s, one const, one non-const, and increment the size only in the latter.

This simple an easy but **will not always work properly**, as you might happen at some time to accidentially invoke the 'operator[] as read' but without the const constraint determinable at that point by compiler. I cannot currently say exactly when and how and if it is possible at all, but I imagine that you can hit that quite easily if you are not very careful with constness.

If you hit that, then the only option known to me would be to provide a wrapper for returned value in non-const mode and leave normal for const mode:

```
myMap::valueType const & operator[](key...) const
mymap::wrapper<myMap::valueType>& operator[](key...)
```

your wrapper would remember a ref& to your Map and woudl remember the KEY and that wrapper would provide an implicit conversion-TO-valueType, and it would provide an assignement operator FROM-valueType-TO-wrappertype. The implicit conversion-to-valuetype woudl perform a read-from-map-fromunder-given-key and would not increment te counter, while the operator=(from-valuetype, to-wrappertype) would perform a write to the map..

That would surely work, but this approach **might be outdated**. I'm not fluent with changes from c'11, so maybe some nicer option is available now - for example, the move `&&`  semantics might change something here, i.e. maybe an overload

```
 valueType&& operator[](key)
```

is also possible ---- but **I have no idea**. I know only the return-a-transparent-wrapper approach.

EDIT: here's a nice (seems complete) example of a proper operator[] overloads that support both reading and writing and that distinguishes between those two:

[stack: How to do some stuff with values assigned in subscript operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12249696/717732)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to discriminate between reading and writing operations the solution is to return a proxy object from `operator []`.

For an example see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16132858/320726

Answer (score 0):

You increment your `size` only when `key` is not present in `keys`, right? That's what `std::map` does. So if you just printing the contents of the map you'll be reading values for existing keys, so `size` won't be incremented.

Comment: You're right, i only increment size when key isn't present, and you're doublely right, i try to rewrite the std::map Class. But I want to std::cout a key wich is not in my class and I want as output a std::endl

Comment: (cut:was wrong), and this is the very problem: he does not want to increase it when he uses the operator[] to read.